# Types of url arguments when linking via <a> tag in django template

Tags: django-templates, django-urls

What is the difference between these linkings?:

```
<a href="{% url 'entry' title %}">Some Page</a>
```

and

```
<a href="{% url 'entry' title='title' %}">Some Page</a> .
```

I've worked with the first one, and can't understand why we need to write like `title='title'` in the second one.

Comment: are you sure there is a url routing like second one? i haven't seen it by now

Comment: Share the relevant `path(...)`.

Comment: @RezaGH: yes, that is with *named* parameters.

Comment: @RezaGH Yes, there is

Comment: interesting....

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry"),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second you are passing `'title'` as a *string literal* to the *url parameter* `title`, so this will work if your path looks like:

```
path('entry/<slug:title>/', some_view, name='entry')
```

for example. If the path looks like:

```
path('entry/<slug:slug>/', some_view, name='entry')
```

the name of the parameter is thus `slug`, not `title`. Regardless if you want to pass the *value* of the title variable, you should use:

```
<a href="{% url 'entry' title=title %}">Some Page</a>
```

or in case the URL parameter is `slug`:

```
<a href="{% url 'entry' slug=title %}">Some Page</a>
```

Comment: Why are you not using single quotes like `title='title'`? Does it work without it also?

Comment: @Fayzulla: the point is that if you use `title='title'` you use the *string* `title` as value, so this will generate a url `wiki/title`, it thus does not look to the *variable* `title`.

Comment: If I will use like this: `<a href="{% url 'entry' title %}">Some Page</a>` , does it mean that I didn't change the value of the `title`? Diff between `title` and `title=title` I mean.

Comment: @Fayzulla: there is no difference between `title` and `title=title`.

Comment: @Fayzulla: the `title=`... is the name of the *url parameter*, and the `=title` is the *template variable* that we use. You can both use positional and named parameters in a `{% url ... %}` template tag.

Comment: Ah, understood. And does it work with `<str:title>` also? Is there a big diff between `<str:title>` and `<slug:title>`?

Comment: @Fayzulla: yes, the `str:` or `slug:` part specifies only what values are allowed, for `slug:` it only allows a slug, which is more restrictive. Slugs are however more visually pleasant than `str` when there are accents, spaces, symbols, etc. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/glossary/#term-slug).

Comment: I think I just figured it out, thanks a lot. And could you please help me with my other question here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087051/understanfding-the-initial-argument-of-the-form-in-django-form-initial